# Printing JSON response with JSONP :AJAX

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax, jsonp

I am trying to print a JSON response from an ajax call to a URL. The JSON is not being print.

But, when i  debug using the chrome debugger i could see the json being populated in the preview

http://localhost:17770/api/v1/Profile?callback=jQuery112402874304526465612_1500350361459&_=1500350361461

> [{userID: "bravo1234", userName: "bravo",…}, {userID: "lima1234",
>   userName: "lima",…},…] 0 : {userID: "bravo1234", userName: "bravo",…}
>   1 : {userID: "lima1234", userName: "lima",…} 2 : {userID:
>   "foxtrot1234", userName: "foxtrot",…} 3 : {userID: "julie1234",
>   userName: "julie",…} 4 : {userID: "tango1234", userName: "tango",…} 5
>   : {userID: "julie1234", userName: "julie",…} 6 : {userID:
>   "charlie1234", userName: "charlie",…} 7 : {userID: "phani1234",
>   userName: "phani",…} 8 : {userID: "newUser1234", userName:
>   "newUser",…} 9 : {userID: "dhanilan1234", userName: "dhanilan",…} 10 :
>   {userID: "user1234", userName: "string",…} 11 : {userID:
>   "adminuser1234", userName: "admin",…} 12 : {userID: "shreyas1234",
>   userName: "shreyas",…} 13 : {userID: "newuser12345", userName:
>   "newuser",…}

```
$("#button_1").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://localhost:17770/api/v1/Profile",
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
                async: false,
                success: function(result){
                    debugger;
                    alert('hi');
                    $("#divhtml").html(result);
                console.log(result)
        }
        });
        });
```

I found that the function success is not being called. What could be the potential reason behind this behavior.

I have seen many questions in stackoverflow regarding JSONP but nothing fixed this issue so far.

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: @31piy no error